# Android and Microsoft ActiveSync problems

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, android, activesync

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server with Exchange 2010 installed, and I'm having trouble to set up the Microsoft ActiveSync properly.

Right now it works wonders with iPad and iPhone, but something is happening with Android devices that is driving me crazy.

First problem happens during the account setup. It takes too long to set up the account, and it will often fail saying the connection with the server failed. I just keep trying without changing the parameters and it eventually works.

Once the account is added, I go to the Inbox and there is no mail. Telling the device to sync manually aparently has no effect, it does not say it failed either. It will eventually sync the folder after several minutes. Sending emails seems to work just fine.

Opening a message will often display no body. After a while it says the connection with the server failed, and later it works.

The latency with the server is quite high, but iPhone and iPad have none of those problems, I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Another problem happens with a Samsung Galaxy Tab where I cannot install the ActiveSync account at all. The IIS logs accuse HTTP error 449, that [according to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd891478.aspx) means that "insufficient information was provided by the client". No idea what to do about that either.

Answer (score 1):

Does this give you a clean bill of health?  https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/
Are you using a self signed cert? (though I think you are passed that being an issue)
Do the users have too many mobile device partnerships?
I don't think it is a lack of ActiveSync persmissions for the mailbox, that would prevent the connection wizard from moving forward.

Your 449 error seems to be the server telling the client to re-provision.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh509085(v=exchg.140).aspx

I have maybe 30-40 Android devices (Samsung, HTC, Motorola) all running on Exchange 2010 (v14.1 Build 123.4).  Even in cases of highly latent connections on mobile devices, like when traveling overseas on 2G and 3G, I haven't had any users complain about ActiveSync not working.  But admittedly, I've never tried to setup ActiveSync over that connection.  Have you tried it over wifi or on another connection that is reasonably fast?  Once connected, the latent connection shouldn't be an issue other than to delay syncing which most users won't notice.

Comment: I reviewed the settings, and "Allow non-provisionable devices" is checked. Aparently its by default. But despite of that the Android devices where it works still warn that "some functions of the device will be controlled remotely" (or something like that) when installing the account. testconnectivity.microsoft.com fails on certificate, but I can tell the device to trust any certificate so I don't think its the issue.

Comment: Does the mobile partnership show up in EMC under that user for that device?  Are any of these users setup on Apple devices as well?  (Meaning do you know for sure these accounts work elsewhere).  Failing on the cert is expected if you are using a self signed.  It's an odd problem to have Apple work and not Android.  Samsung and Motorola both don't use the stock ActiveSync client, they use their own.  Not sure if it matters, but it might be something specific to that client/device? (thinking out loud here).

Comment: I cant check that right now but yeah, there are other devices set up with the same user account.